# Make Php string without break lines

Tags: php, xml

i need to generate random sentences from dictionary. In dictionary is every word at one line, firstly i load this dictionary to array and after it i have a for cycle and randomly pickup some data, but if i wrote it, so it is at one line in browser, but in source code is every word at another line. Then I need to create a set of XML files from search engine and this new lines are indexed as `/n/r` and in XML source code it has got a symbol `&#xD;` So my question is how i can make a sentence which will be at one line in source code too. Thanks.

Here is piece of my code i don´t have here randomly loading data, i only made it for illustration in for cycle.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
$data = array();
while (($buffer = fgets($file)) !== false) {
  $data[] = $buffer;
}

$sentence = '';

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  $sentence = $sentence . $data[$i];
}
```

Comment: I know, so html uses <br>. I do not want to use it right, I need to be on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to filter new line characters.
In your code use:

```
$data[] = trim($buffer);
```